# Why is my custom theme only partially applying (antd)?

Tags: reactjs, themes, antd

I am using Ant Design in a React project of mine, and I am attempting to make use of their custom theming available in version 5 (5.1.2 installed) according to documentation [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme). However, the custom theme appears to only apply to certain components while skipping others altogether. In the below example, the darker background color is applied to the `Content` and `Footer` components while the `Header` and `Sider` components are left with the default color, and the `Header` and `Footer` components have updated foreground colors, but the `Sider` and `Content` components do not. What am I missing to make this theme apply in full to each of these components?

Example:

`src/index.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';

import theme from './theme';
import reducers from './reducers';
import App from './components/App';

const store = createStore(reducers)
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <ConfigProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
      </ConfigProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

`src/theme.js`

```js
import { theme } from 'antd';

const custom_theme = {
    algorithm: theme.darkAlgorithm,
    token: {
        colorPrimary: '#e02820',
        borderRadius: 5,
        wireframe: false
    },
}

export default custom_theme;
```

`src/components/App.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'antd';

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout;

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Header>header</Header>
                <Layout>
                    <Sider>sider</Sider>
                    <Content>content</Content>
                </Layout>
                <Footer>footer</Footer>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Result:
[image: resulting colors when loaded]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm seeing the same behavior.

Comment: @dhysong IIRC, what ended up working for me was uninstalling and reinstalling my node modules. I think I had somehow corrupted my installed version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are importing the components from the right location. My IDE was auto-importing components from locations that exported versions of the components that did not read from the applied theme.

E.G. (incorrect) `import Button from 'antd/lib/button';`
instead of (correct) `import { Button } from 'antd/es';`

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with AntD custom theme as well and have found that not every attribute can be updated. The main changes allowed are `colorPrimary` and according to the documentation based on this color their algorithm chooses the rest of the color pallet that matches.

From documentation - "Brand color is one of the most direct visual elements to reflect the characteristics and communication of the product. After you have selected the brand color, we will automatically generate a complete color palette and assign it effective design semantics."

That being said you can try to be even more specific. By that I mean you can specify the style for each separate component.

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      components: {
        Header: {
          colorPrimary: '#00b96b',
        },
        Footer: {
          colorPrimary: '#fff',
       },
      },
    }}
  >
```

Just change and add your desired styles to each component. If it still does not change, then that is the color AntD will let you have based for each component based on your choice of primary color.

Another option would be to use styled-components library to further provide the styles to AntD components that are not possible using Ants Config API.

If this provides the valid solution would you please click the green arrow on my response to inform others of the solution.